infinite clause in x bar theory
Can anyone tell me how to deal with the sentence like "it is impossible for him to finish it" in x-bar? I have been trying to figure it out based on what I know about x bar, but I cannot. "him" is [+ACC] which needs to get its case after it moves. I firstly come up with AgroP, but I do not know at where I should put it. Because "him" is originally generated at spec of VoiceP(or vP) to get its agent theta role. And it moves to spec of TP in embedded clause to check EPP. But it cannot move to spec of AgroP further because it is between 'for' and 'to' and it will definitely violate the word order in English.

In brief: "for" is the exceptional case of a complementiser that assigns case. The whole "for-to" construction is a clause on a par with a "that"-clause (in which "that" is a complementiser). So, It is impossible that he can finish is similar to your example. In X-bar terms: "for" is a C-head with an IP complement, the head of IP is infinitival "to".
Derivation in a simple version of generative grammar:

Impossible + CP
CP = C°:for + IP
IP = NP:him + I'
I' = I°:to + VP
VP = V°:finish + NP:it

The case assignment is objective case assigned by "for" to the specifier of its complement. This certainly comes from the fact that "for" is originally a preposition; it has developed into a C in this construction but retained the old case marking habit. The result within the new structure is classical "exceptional case marking" (ECM) as in I expect IP[him to come]. In this latter example case marking is by the verb, in your example it is by a C-head, both are outside the IP and select it, and, by way of exception, assign their case feature to the specifier of their complement instead of to the whole complement (because the IP complement actually doesn't need case).
This whole analysis is very old; it's already found in Chomsky (1981) Lectures on Government and Binding, p. 53 (in my 1993 reprint). It seems to me it might not be compatible with "AgrO" structures, but I'd say this just shows that AgrO is superfluous.
See also: Can a complementizer (C) take two complements (COMPS)?
